# how to write a path in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sqlcmd, shared-directory

I wrote a batch file for making a SQL Express back up.

I tested it first and it was working well but when I created another and I changed the path to an external hard drive it stopped working.

Here is a minimal example:

```
echo off
cls
sqlcmd -S GETRASCOSAGE01\SAGE100 -E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='\\NET-HD\Backup_sage\', @backupType='F'"
```

and here is the minimal example of the previous working code:

```
echo off
cls
sqlcmd -S GETRASCOSAGE01\SAGE100 -E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SAGE100\MSSQL\Backup\', @backupType='F'"
```

Comment: If you were to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49320871/edit) and include the one that was working well, we would have something to compare it with!

Comment: OK @Compo .....